# How to implement discount for products in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement a discount for each individual product in a catalogue.
I added new field to Products table - discount.
How do I recalculate product.price if discount.present?

I tried to add helper to product.rb:

```
def price
 old_price = self.price
 if self.discount.present?
  self.price -= self.price / self.discount
 else
  old_price
end
```

But it gets me to "Stack level too deep" error

Comment: "Stack level too deep" almost always means you have an infinite recursion problem.  A function calling itself without a stop condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this error because `price` is constantly referencing itself. You would be much better off by creating a new method to display the price.

```
def price_with_discount
  return self.price if self.discount.nil? || self.discount.zero?
  self.price - (self.price / self.discount)
end
```

And then you use that in your view

```
<%= product.price_with_discount %>
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I need to display both, new and old price?

Comment: Then just display the price, `<%= product.price %>`

Comment: That's the good thing about separating the two, so you can display whichever you want.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry it took sometime to reply.